# Animations in Internet Explorer when gif files are blocked

Tags: html

An application running on our company intranet used to use a jquery opacity animation to show a bunch of blinking indicators. As many of our systems are old and slow I updated this with an animated gif which drastically improved the responsiveness and page scrolling of the browser.

I then discovered that the majority of our users, who access the site through a terminal server, have internet explorer animations disabled through a group policy. Therefore they can't see the animating gif. It's hopeless asking the admins to enable this, they just cite performance issues etc. Is there any html code I can use to trick IE into allowing this image to animate? If not, what is the best (least processor / memory intensive) way of displaying an animation if I can't use a gif?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going on the fact "blinking indicators" sounds like quite minimal animation, have you looked into css3 animations?  Needs IE10+, though.

Also: JQuery is a big library for just an animation.  Raw javascript may keep things smaller.

Comment: Yeah, I have a hard time imagining that properly-written JavaScript would be significantly more resource-intensive than GIF. Which is actually pretty inefficient.

Comment: Thanks, will give css animations a try and see how it performs. edit: Noted re JQuery, it's used extensively for other functions as well though. The script performs fine when there's only one or two elements, but it gets worse when there's multiple elements animating.